# Why segmentation fault in this simple C ++ program?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, merge, segmentation-fault

I am trying to merge two sorted subarrays. I have spent hourse of frustration removing **segmentation fault** error in vs code but with no success.

- I am using a temporary array to store the newly ordered array.
- comparing elements of two subarrays simultaneously and incrementing the index of the subarray whose **arr[index]** is smaller.
- Copying the leftover elements of the subarray whose traversal index has not reached the end.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

void merge(int start1,int end1,int start2,int end2,int arr[],int temp_arr[]){
    int i = start1;
    int j = start2;
    while (i <= end1 && j <= end2)
    {
        if(arr[i] < arr[j]){
            //using start1 as index on purpose
            temp_arr[start1++] = arr[i];
            i++; 
        }else{
            temp_arr[start1++] = arr[j];
            j++;
        }
    }

    //if first array elements are left
    while(i <= end1 ){
        temp_arr[start1++] = arr[i];
    }

    //if second array elements are left
    while(j <= end2){
        temp_arr[start1++] = arr[j];
    }
    
}

int main(){
    int arr[] = {5,6,7,1,2,3};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    int temp[n];//temporary array
    int a;
    //to find where the next sorted subarray begins
    for(int i = 0;i <n-1;i++){
        if(arr[i] > arr[i+1]){
            a= i;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    merge(0,a,a+1,n-1,arr,temp);

    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
        cout << temp[i] << " ";
    }




}
```

Comment: `int temp[n];` is not valid C++.

Comment: `a` is not guaranteed to be initialized depending on how `arr` is arranged.

Comment: @ChrisMM VLAs being nonstandard is pedantry, not the source of the problem.

Comment: @Aryaman You should get into the habit of compiling with `-fsanitize=address,undefined`. It can catch all sorts of bugs.

Comment: @o11c, while not related to the problem, it's still very relevant for anyone wanting to program in C++ professionally, or even submitting code to be evaluated for course work. That would not compile on many different compilers.

Comment: If the VLA was the source of the problem ChrisMM probably would have written an answer and not a comment.

Comment: @011c,what is it? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an infinite loop:

```
while(i <= end1 ){
    temp_arr[start1++] = arr[i];
}
```

So is this one.

```
while(j <= end2){
    temp_arr[start1++] = arr[j];
}
```

In both cases, since neither `i`, `j`, `end1`, nor `end2` ever change in these loops, `start1` will keep increasing way past the array boundary, introducing more undefined behavior on each iteration that makes an assignment.

That may not be your only bug.

Comment: Oh God!!!! I have wasted a lot of time on this . Seriously , I was overlooking such a simple thing. Thanks a lot and lot.

Comment: Does this way of posting questions with comments and explicit mention of some important points affect the readiness of the code and problem? Does  this help in getting a good answer or is it just an overwork for me?

Comment: @Aryaman - You posted a reasonable question with an [mcve].  That makes for an acceptable question.  The C++ community on SO is quite competitive with regards to Q&A, so it can come across as a little harsh.  However, you would have found the answer yourself if you had just inserted a reasonable number of `printf` or `cout` statements within your code in order to identify which line it was crashing on.  Or if you had simply used an IDE debugger, you could have stepped through it and validated the program state until you noticed your loops were infinite. Why didn't you do that?